# Requesting permission to use the site logo as the Twitter account's profile pic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, site-promotion

> **This request has been declined. Please see the followup question:
>   [Design a profile picture for our Twitter account!](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/699/481)**

Now that [we have a community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/481), I'd like to know if we could use Stack Exchange's logo for this site as the profile picture for the Twitter account. I'd noticed that the [Mi Yodeyan Twitter account](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya) uses their Stack Exchange logo as their profile picture. (I assume they asked permission first, as [they did for their publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3560/5323).)

The [Trademark Guidance page](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) says (among other things):

> **Do not** use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc.
>
> **Do not** use our name or logo in a way that might imply a false sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.

I do recognize that we don't yet have a perfect name for the account; however, I made sure to emphasize that this account is unofficial and community-run in both the bio and the pinned tweet. I hope that the use of the logo will increase brand recognition and improve the image of that Twitter account (and will save me the effort of creating a profile picture `:-)`).

Once I'm asking...I'm not yet certain what we'll use for the header photo. I might try to find a stock photo (or take a picture) of a bunch of books or a library, or I might just take a screen shot of the "Questions/Tags/Users/Badges/Unanswered/Ask Question" bar at the top of the page. If we want to, could we use that for our header photo?

Pretty please? Thank you :)

Comment: If the answer to this is "no", there are plenty of images [over here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/395/17) which might be usable.

Comment: Good idea, @Randal'Thor.

Comment: Why would we want to use our "logo"? It's just the letters "LIT". I personally think we should go with something more creative

Comment: @Hamlet I see your point, but it would also help people recognize that the account has something to do with the site (It *is* the letters "LIT," but it's in a Stack Exchange speech bubble). If you have a better idea, maybe post an answer and see what people make of it.

Comment: @Shokhet fair enough

Comment: And if (hopefully more like when) this site graduates, you should definitely use the logo then if allowed

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be more productive to post this on main meta?

Comment: @Gallifreyan I dunno, maybe. CMs look for [meta-tag:feature-request] posts on all metas, and Mith already pinged one of them in chat. (I suspect that this might have been closed/migrated on MSE, because it really only has to do with one site)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really cool that you want to do this, but unfortunately we can't let you use the site logo for the account. The reasoning comes down to the way current trademark rules work. I won't belabor that point since you're clearly already familiar with our trademark guidance page.

We absolutely support the idea of the initiative, though! For example, if and when your site reaches the point where it gets a custom design, we may be able to help you use some of those assets, as the Worldbuilding site [did with their community blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3614/may-and-should-we-use-the-site-design-on-our-blog#comment9819_3614). If you have more questions or ideas, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wish it could be different, but I guess that's just the way things are.