# Design a profile picture for our Twitter account!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As our [request to use the site favicon](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/691/requesting-permission-to-use-the-site-logo-as-the-twitter-accounts-profile-pic/698#698) was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), we need something else.

The goals:

1. Design a suitable **profile picture** for the [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackLiterature), that sizes well, and has something to do with books/literature and
   isn't copyrighted or anything. ([recommended dimensions are 400x400 pixels](https://support.twitter.com/articles/127871))
2. Design (or find) a suitable picture for the account's **header picture.** (recommended dimensions are 1500x500 pixels)

Can you help find or make something?

This post is also for discussion about ideas. If you have an idea... Post it below!

Let's make this look good! ;)

Comment: See also https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/395/481 for inspiration. (Nothing there is quite right, at the moment. Too much detail for such a small picture.)

Comment: [Here's](http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/hledej.php?hleda=book) a collection of public-domain book images.

Answer (score 4):

How's this: a fancy letter `L`? [Taken from the public domain](https://archive.org/stream/dasaltebuchundse00gerl#page/94/mode/2up).

[image: The letter "L" in ornate text]

[You can see it in action on our tumblr](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/).

(Just so I remember, the background image on the tumblr is also from the public domain: [it comes from a series of tapestries about unicorns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lady_and_the_Unicorn#The_tapestries).)

Comment: I _can't_ see it in action on your Tumblr :D Did you turn the avatar off?

Answer (score 2):

I like [@Hamlet's idea](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/805/58) of an `L`, but I think that it would be a better idea if we had a magnifying glass, magnifying perhaps the word 'Lit'. This implies that we're about going into depth and analysis. Perhaps this 'Lit' could be made out of words, and the magnifying glass showing some of those words, but I don't know if that's necessary.

Comment: Maybe the word "Literature" or "Lit" with a magnifying glass focusing on "Lit" or "L"?

Answer (score 2):

[image: .] [image: .]

[An initial letter S with a beautiful miniature painting of a chronicler writing in a desk.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/K%C3%A9pes_kr%C3%B3nika_%C3%ADr%C3%B3de%C3%A1k.jpg)  [I suggested this in chat as an alternative to images with just a letter L.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38859669#38859669)  [The image comes from Képes Krónika, a famous codex of history from the 14th century.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:K%C3%A9pes_kr%C3%B3nika_%C3%ADr%C3%B3de%C3%A1k.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure how clearly that's going to show up in such a small format as the Twitter icon.

Comment: @Mithical You're right, I should show them in small sizes in first place.  I edited the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea for a profile picture, but I think we could use a header picture that matches our monthly challenge. [This month, we're reading Icelandic Sagas](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/700/481), so I think we should have a header picture that has to do with Iceland!

I suggest something along the lines of the image below:

[image: The pattern of Iceland's flag superimposed on an outline of Iceland.]
<sup>([src](https://www.deviantart.com/tag/icelandflag))</sup>

I have no idea if we can use this picture; I don't understand how deviantart works. The picture is just there as an illustration of what I'm thinking of. Can you find something similar in the public domain? Or, better yet, create something like this?

Comment: Unless they state otherwise, you would have to give the creator of that image credit.

Comment: Not sure if I like this idea. It might give the impression that we're *only* about Icelandic sagas (or whatever) in that period, and turn off people who would otherwise be interested in the site.

Comment: @Hamlet I'm not sure. I was confused by https://about.deviantart.com/policy/copyright/, which said, among other things, "Just about anything that is on this site, on the web, on TV, on CD's, on DVD's, in books & in magazines is probably copyrighted by someone. [...] Also do not confuse the fact that a work is publicly available with the idea that it is in the public domain or free for use. Being easy to find on the internet does not affect a work's copyrighted status." So...I don't know. If someone can decipher that and explain it I'd be more comfortable with it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I don't think so. Profile pictures and name speak to identity, headers can be expected to change over time. See eg http://talkingpointsmemo.com/livewire/merriam-webster-election-day-gotterdammerung. (I'm not really a Twitter expert, but I'm fairly certain people won't think we're *only* sagas, especially if they see most of the tweets on the page talk about more general literature. But I understand your concern.)

Comment: @Shokhet it means probably don't use the image without permission, and if you do use the image without permission, make sure you cite the source.

Comment: Okay, @Hamlet. [`](https://example.com)

Comment: @Randal'Thor What about a picture of a flag with the words "topic of the month"? I'll see if I can design something tomorrow with my limited MS Paint ability. (I have GIMP but never used it much. Probably don't need it anyway.)

Comment: If you want to go with this idea, [one for this month](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/O2SeGbbseWg/maxresdefault.jpg) (h/t to [@Mithrandir](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=38347245#38347245)) :-) The source I believe is some Youtuber; not sure how/whether this would align with copyright stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[image: L] [image: L]

[An ornate letter L from a heading font.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgllm.jpg)  [I suggested this one in chat when Shoket asked for a letter L,](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38859578#38859578) because the other suggestions didn't look good in a circular frame.  I took it [from an 1906 book of header fonts, so the image is in public domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_signist's_book_of_modern_alphabets,_plain_and_ornamental,_ancient_and_medi%C3%A6val,_from_the_eighth_to_the_twentieth_century,_with_numerals_%281906%29_%2814583795179%29.jpg).